# How to select multiple rows from the same table only using one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table from MySQL and I want to select some rows from this table without having to use lots of queries to find single rows.

My code currently is something like that :

```
$query = "SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo = '101' ";

$query2 = "SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo = '102' ";

$query3= "SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo = '103' ";

$query4 = "SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo = '104' ";
```

And I don't like it, because for me it seems useless this code but I don't know a better way to find a solution to this, as I am new to PHP.

I want something like that if possible :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM conteudo";
```

And while selecting all the table, I could choose what value I would display, without having multiple queries. How can I make that work ?

Comment: Use a function to abstract away the repetitive nature of your queries. Or, as you've already wrote, select all the records, and then iterate over them in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways:

Using between:

```
SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo BETWEEN 101 AND 104;
```

This fetches every row with an ID between those two number. If I remember correctly, the lower end is inclusive and the higher end is exclusive.

Alternatively, if they are not consecutive:

```
SELECT def_conteudo FROM conteudo WHERE nro_conteudo IN (101, 102, 103, 104);
```

This will fetch the ID's in the list.

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you. +1 and correct answer (in 5 mins)  :)